# TLS client authentication with Nginx and Tomcat web application

Tags: tomcat, ssl, nginx, tls1.2

I have a Tomcat 8 web application, it runs on the port 8080 on the server. Any incoming request to port 443 is forwarded to localhost:8080 using Nginx to serve the web application.

I am trying to set up mutual authentication & then parse the client cert that was used for the authentication by the application. This information will then be used by the application to decide if the user should have `admin` or `user` rights. The client cert will bear the string `admin` or `user` in the Common Name (CN) field.

I am able to achieve the mutual authentication & below is the current nginx ssl.conf But the problem is that the cert info is not passed to the tomcat web application to parse the data. Is there a way available in nginx to pass on the client cert data, so the tomcat8 application can use that?

```
server {
    listen       443 default_server;
    server_name  name.domain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/self-signed.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/self-signed.pem;
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;


    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ca.cert.pem;
    ssl_verify_client optional;
    ssl_verify_depth  2;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;


    port_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    #test page for the load balancer
    location /loadbalancer {
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
      auth_basic off;
      #proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      try_files $uri /test.html;
    }

    location /webapi {
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
      auth_basic off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location / {
      if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS)

     {
      return 403;
      break;
     }

      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }


    error_page  404              /404.html;
      location = /404.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) directive to pass additional headers to your tomcat.

Available variables

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_cipher

Example

```
proxy_set_header SSL_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

In your Java app you can read this headers for further processing.

On a side note I would not save the access level in the certificate but in a server side database, that way you could reassign / change / add roles easier  <s>or revoke a valid certificate.</s>

**EDIT**
Actually nginx supports certificate revocation lists as well:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_crl

Good article for nginx + php which can be easily adapted into your use case:

http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi

Comment: This `proxy_set_header SSL_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;` indeed worked! thank you.

Comment: Note, that if you want the full certificate, there are two variables: `ssl_client_cert` where Nginx will replace `\n` with tabs; and `ssl_client_raw_cert` which has new lines but breaks your HTTP connection.

Using the [official Tomcat SSL Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/SSLValve.html) doesn't work (only replaces withspaces and not tabs)

Comment: And the official Nginx doc for ssl_client_cert does not seem to mention that "\n" are replaced. Only mentions "\t" are prepended (but \n is actually replaced): http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html

Comment: This is a good post about the topic (and the `\n` issue):
https://blog.perplexedminds.com/2015/04/nginx-apache-tomcat-certificate.html

Comment: @OK999 - After adding the proxy_set_header, does it work exactly as if client authentication were present on tomcat? i.e were you able to receive the certificate in the X509AuthenticationFilter class at 
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])((X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")) ?